# Sqlite3: How to URLEncode query results?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sqlite

I have a system where it connects to a SMS Gateway.I use sqlite3 to connect to the database of the Gateway. The system connects to the Gateway and retrieves messages then saves it to an Oracle database. My problem is that the format of the messages disappears once I set the values of the message to an object.
Is there any way to encode the message in the query?

I've tried doing this:
`SELECT URLENCODE(*) FROM SMSRECV;`

I know that this is not a proper function, but I still tried because I really can't find a way

Connecting to the gateway via ssh

```
private String getSmsDump() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            String command = "sqlite3 /persistent/var/lib/asterisk/db/MyPBX.sqlite \".read /persistent/script/cwms/smsrecv_html.sqlc\"";
            String host = this.sshHost;
            String user = this.sshUser;
            String password = this.sshPassword;
            int port = this.sshPort;

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();

            try {
                InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
                String line = null;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputReader.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error("BUFFERED READER ERROR: "+ex);
            }

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

        } catch (JSchException | IOException ex) {

            LOGGER.error("SSH CONNECTION ERROR: "+ex);
        }

        return sb.toString();

    } // end getSmsHtmlDump()
```

Setting the values to an object:

```
  public List<SmsMessage> getSmsMessages() {

        List<SmsMessage> result = new ArrayList();
        String smsDump = getSmsDump();
        String received = "RECEIVED";
        String status = "1";
        if (null != smsDump) {
            Document messageDump = Jsoup.parse("<html><head></head><body><table>" + smsDump + "</table></body></html>");
            Elements rows = messageDump.getElementsByTag("tr");
            String hasRead = "0"; //no
            // Lambda expression for iterating row elements
            rows.stream().map((Element row) -> {
                SmsMessage message = new SmsMessage();
                Elements cols = row.getElementsByTag("td");
                message.setMessageId(cols.get(0).text());   // Message ID
                message.setSender(cols.get(1).text());      // Sender
                message.setSmsc(cols.get(2).text());        // SMSC
                message.setPortId(cols.get(3).text());      // Port ID
                message.setContent(cols.get(4).text());  
                                LOGGER.debug(cols.get(4).text());// Content
                message.setReceiveTime(cols.get(5).text()); // Receive Time
                message.setHasRead(hasRead);    // Has Read
                message.setTypeOfMessage(received);
                message.setMessageStatus(status);
                return message;
            }).forEachOrdered((message) -> {
                result.add(message);
                //LOGGER.debug(message.toString());
            });
        }

        return result;

    } // end getSmsMessages()
```

Content of the `smsrecv_html.sqlc` file:

```
.mode html
SELECT * FROM SMSRECV;
```

I just want to set the values to the object without removing the format

Hope you could help me.

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling out to the sqlite3 shell to run a query instead of just doing it in java directly with jdbc or whatever? Er... I'd fix that first. Then use java to encode the results a row at a time.

Comment: Yes, The database of the Gateway is mysql and my application is using oracle. Won't that have a conflict? @shawn